# Make Publications section on thesis

Tags: thesis, report

I would like to make a section in my Ph.D. thesis dedicated to the publications (structured as if it is a chapter).

This is the code I am currently using for my thesis (without considering the package list):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,cucitura]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,outer=3.2cm,bottom=3.5cm,inner=2.2cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % how to display variable names
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$\displaystyle }X<{$}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref

\hypersetup{%
    pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
    bookmarksopen,                                                         
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue},
    citecolor={red},
    urlcolor={blue}
  }
  
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}\errorcontextlines=9

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\tableofcontents

\fancyhead[RO,LE]{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{}

\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
    }

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Chapter1/Chapter1}
\input{Chapter2/Chapter2}
\input{Chapter3/Chapter3}
\input{Chapter4/Chapter4}
\input{Chapter5/Chapter5}

\begin{appendices}
\input{Appendix1/Appendix1}
\input{Appendix2/Appendix2}
\input{Appendix3/Appendix3}
 ()\end{appendices}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliography{thesisbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

How can I insert the publications section?

Comment: Maybe  the `biblatex-publist` package would do what you want?

Comment: And then the code for inserting the publication list how would it look like?

Comment: `biblatex-publist` looks like it's conceived to typeset one's list of publications as a standalone document, and not as a part of a master document, like the phd thesis. I say that after a brief look at the documentation.

Comment: Actually, I never used this package. If it can't work as part of the master document, you might try to filter a bibliography containing your publications with a keyword, adding this keyword  (say ‘own’)  to the bibliography items for which you're an author, then print it with a `\printbibliography[keyword=own]` command.

Comment: @Bernard indeed it is the approach I suggested ;)

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days, I've managed to do that as follows, with `biblatex` (which I encourage you to adopt).

Add a keyword in the bibtex entries of the publication of yours, like `keywords  = {mine}`.

Then, for normal references, use `\printbibliography[notkeyword=mine]` (so that your publications are filtered out).

Then, with the help of `refcontext`, create your list of publications.
I used `\nocite{}` to set the order of appearance, since `refcontext` is called with `[sorting = none]`.
By using `\nocite{}`, it is assumed that your works are not referenced throughout the text, and are only listed at the end of the manuscript.
This is also the reason why `notkeyword` is required in the previous step.

```
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=none]
    \defbibnote{myprenote}{If you wish to add explanations}
    \nocite{mypaper1,mypaper2}
    \printbibliography[%
        title        = {List of Publications},
        prenote      = myprenote,
        keyword      = mine,
    ]
\end{refcontext}
```

A MWE is:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @book{knuth1997art,
        title={The Art of Computer Programming: Fundamental algorithms},
        author={Knuth, D.E. and Addison-Wesley},
        number={v. 1},
        isbn={9780201896831},
        lccn={97002147},
        series={Addison-Wesley series in computer science and information processing},
        url={https://books.google.it/books?id=B31GAAAAYAAJ},
        year={1997},
        publisher={Addison-Wesley}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mypublications.bib}
    @book{mypaper1,
        title={The Art of something else},
        author={me},
        % isbn={ },
        % lccn={},
        keywords  = {mine},
        year={2020},
        publisher={the publisher},
    }
    @book{mypaper2,
        title={The Art of something else 2},
        author={me},
        % isbn={ },
        keywords  = {mine},
        % lccn={},
        year={2020},
        publisher={the publisher},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
    bibstyle     = ieee,
    citestyle    = numeric,
    % isbn         = true,
    % doi          = false,
    % % sorting      = nty,
    % % sorting     = none,
    % % sorting     = debug,
    % url          = false,
    % defernumbers = true,
    % bibencoding  = utf8,
    % backend      = biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\addbibresource{mypublications.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth1997art}
\printbibliography[notkeyword=mine]
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=none]
    \defbibnote{myprenote}{If you wish to add explanations}
    \nocite{mypaper1,mypaper2}
    \printbibliography[%
        title        = {List of Publications},
        prenote      = myprenote,
        keyword      = mine,
    ]
\end{refcontext}
\end{document}
```

Indeed you don't need to separate `references.bib` from `mypublications.bib`, but it is likely that you are going to use the different`bib` files of your papers separately, and it is fastest to add those files separately, instead of merging them (unless there are duplicates, of course).

[image]

Comment: Always my best regards...and +1.